# Can someone other than Professor Dumbledore teleport objects a long distance away?

Tags: harry-potter

*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* chapter 3 describes how Professor Dumbledore picks up Harry at the Privet Drive house when he leaves the Dursley's for the start of his sixth school year.  Harry packs his luggage for the school, but they don't take it with them to the visit to Horace Slughorn.

> ‘Bye,’ said Harry hastily to the Dursleys, and followed Dumbledore, who paused beside Harry's trunk, upon which Hedwig's cage was perched.
>
> ‘We do not want to be encumbered by these just now,’ he said, pulling out his wand again. ‘I shall **send them to The Burrow to await us there**. However, I would like you to bring your Invisibility Cloak … just in case.’
>
> *[…]* Dumbledore waved his wand and the trunk, cage and Hedwig vanished.

It appears that Professor Dumbledore can teleport objects to far away from him, without he himself going with the objects.  Is this something only Professor Dumbledore could do?  Or is there an example for some other wizard capable of doing the same?

Comment: Possible, but I don’t think we ever see it used again

Comment: anyone who summons food is doing essentially the same thing, its the distance that isnt usually seen

Comment: Do you mean using a spell specifically? Because obviously you have magical objects like Vanishing Cabinets, the Sword of Gryffindor, etc.

Comment: Anything Dumbledore can do, Tom Riddle can do better

Comment: @DVK - Except balance things on his nose

Comment: @Richard - assertion not accepted absent canon evidence of Dumbledore being able to balance things on his nose (glasses don't count, they are held by the ears).

Comment: @DVK - Voldemort has no nose, how does he smell?

Comment: @Richard Awful!

Comment: I don't have anything to back this up, but I always assumed he turned Harry's luggage into a portkey(using Portus)..And, of course, any wizard can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There is no other example, but is likely common

It is difficult to prove a negative, but having extensively searched through all Harry Potter books and *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*, and briefly through Pottermore, it seems as there is no other reference to a witch or wizard teleporting objects.

However, it is unlikely that this is exclusive to Dumbledore:

- Harry did not remark that this was anything special, but this may have been due to him being brought up in the Muggle world
- None of the inhabitants of the Burrow made any comment (that we know of) about Harry's trunk and Hedwig's cage suddenly appearing at the Burrow. You'd have thought that if this had never been seen before, one of the Weasleys would have asked something similar to "How did you do that?"